# OmegaConf can I influence how lists are merged

Tags: python, omegaconf

Is there any option to influence how lists are merged in OmegaConf.
Ideally, this could be controlled in the config file, but if there is come switch I can use in the code I'm also interested.

Example:

```
from omegaconf import OmegaConf

conf1 = OmegaConf.create({"list": [1, 2]})
conf2 = OmegaConf.create({"list": [3, 4]})
conf = OmegaConf.merge(conf1, conf2)
print(conf.pretty())

Output:
list:
- 3
- 4
```

I'd like to have an option to merge, not override lists (that is, have `[1, 2, 3, 4]` as a result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
As of OmegaConf 2.0, lists merge is always replacing the target list.

In an early version this used to do what you want, but I chose to go with the current behavior as it seems more useful for lists.

Comment: Well, that's an authoritative response.

Comment: This might be supported with Structured Configs if/when per-field-metadata is implemented (https://github.com/omry/omegaconf/issues/131)

Comment: That would be a welcome addition. 99% of the cases you want current behaviour, and then you run across one case when you would like the other

Comment: Yup. I will consider it once 131 is implemented. It should be easy enough to add then.